# Which size back pack if between sizes

Tags: backpacking, backpacks

I am looking to get a new Day/Weekend Pack. I have been looking at few in the 32-35L range but I a noticed that at least with Osprey packs I am right in between their S/M  and their M/L. I have a 19in torso.

S/M is for torso's 16-20 and the M/L is for 19-23in. The waist sizes are irrelevant as I will never be under 29in or over 50in.

I have been looking around and cannot find any comments regarding which size to go with I am in between.

Obviously if you go up you get a little more capacity. If you go down it is lighter...slightly.

I am curious if there is a standard out there regarding if you should go up if you can or down.

Comment: I would go to a store, try them on (with weight in them) and see how they feel. It would seem that the S/M nominally fits, the M/L could be on the slightly large size with fewer options to adjust. But, that assumes you have a 19 inch torso, not a 18 3/4, etc., and what they really mean by the sizes (not all size 10 shoes are the same, for example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only answer is to go to a store and try on the sack for real. Take your actual gear to try with it, and use your normal packing technique. Try to choose a store with a trained fitter.

Then take it home on appro and try it around the house for a few hours so you can return it if it doesn't carry well for you. It's worth the effort - a badly fitting pack is an ongoing misery.

Rucksack design and fitting is a very imprecise art - there's no way to tell what will work for you without simply trying it on.

Comment: Exactly. In some stores, they don't even let you buy a backpack without having you walk up and down the store with the bag loaded for a good while.